# Rails Inserting Nested Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest, controllers

We are trying to insert an object into our rails controller (terminology may be wrong i'm new to ruby and rails) that has objects which contain objects. For just the basic portion we are trying to insert a location that has a restaurant, so the restaurant has an id that refers to the location. Ideally we'd like it to only insert the location if it doesn't exist and give it the id after insert, if it already exists just fill in the id that already exists. Right now we are inserting the location but the restaurants insert never happens.

Heres the sample json object we are trying to insert, it also has the other controllers we are trying to insert into. Location has one restaurant that has many inspections that has many violations. Tables are (locations, restaurants, inspections, violations)

```
{
  "locations": {
    "restaurants_attributes": {
      "name": "CORNERSTONE GROUP HOME",
      "type": "INSTITUTION",
      "inspections_attributes": {
        "date": "2013-11-19",
        "number": "26134",
        "violations_attributes": {
          "comment": "WOODEN SHELVING IN DISREPAIR",
          "code": "4-501.11",
          "critical": "0"
        }
      }
    },
    "st_apt_num": "",
    "st_dir": "E",
    "st_number": "1250",
    "st_suffix": "RD",
    "zip_code": "65201",
    "latitude": 38.9808446,
    "longitude": -92.289225
  }
}
```

Here is the models for locations / restaurants

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :restaurants
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :restaurants
end


class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :locations
        has_many :inspections
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :inspections
end
```

Here is the migrate for locations / restaurants

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.integer :st_apt_num
      t.string :st_dir
      t.integer :st_number
      t.string :st_suffix
      t.integer :zip_code
      t.decimal :latitude, :precision => 9, :scale => 7
      t.decimal :longitude, :precision => 9, :scale => 7

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateRestaurants < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :restaurants do |t|
      t.belongs_to :locations
      t.string :name
      t.string :type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the controllers for locations / restaurants (haven't changed anything here though)

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :set_location, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /locations
  # GET /locations.json
  def index
    @locations = Location.all
  end

  # GET /locations/1
  # GET /locations/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /locations/new
  def new
    @location = Location.new
  end

  # GET /locations/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /locations
  # POST /locations.json
  def create
    @location = Location.new(location_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.save
        format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @location }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /locations/1
  # PATCH/PUT /locations/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.update(location_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /locations/1
  # DELETE /locations/1.json
  def destroy
    @location.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to locations_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_location
      @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def location_params
      params.require(:locations).permit(:st_apt_num, :st_dir, :st_number, :st_suffix, :zip_code, :latitude, :longitude)
    end
end

class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :set_restaurant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /restaurants
  # GET /restaurants.json
  def index
    @restaurants = Restaurant.all
  end

  # GET /restaurants/1
  # GET /restaurants/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /restaurants/new
  def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new
  end

  # GET /restaurants/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /restaurants
  # POST /restaurants.json
  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @restaurant.save
        format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @restaurant }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /restaurants/1
  # PATCH/PUT /restaurants/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @restaurant.update(restaurant_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /restaurants/1
  # DELETE /restaurants/1.json
  def destroy
    @restaurant.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to restaurants_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_restaurant
      @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def restaurant_params
      params.require(:restaurant).permit(:name, :loc_id, :type)
    end
end
```

Comment: it should be `has_one: restaurant` and `belongs_to: location` ... notice difference of singulars and plurals...

Comment: I tried switching to singular, still not inserting for restaurant

Comment: try to fix issues everywhere.